# How to cut with a regular expression (or C# functions) TEXT MESSAGE in one variable and the second variable USERNAME from this text?

Tags: c#, regex, json, parsing

How to cut with a regular expression (or С# functions) TEXT MESSAGE in one variable and the second variable USERNAME from this text?

```
{"messages": [{"text": "TEXT MESSAGE", "channel": "main": "from": "USERNAME", "fromid": 651765, "t": 1379970985409, "tc": "f16d7e "}}}
```

Comment: You must have an alternate ID that you use to upvote your own posts...

Comment: That's JSON... why on earth would you use a regex to parse that?

Comment: Deserialize, ??, profit.

Comment: Chris is right. You should be using [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to parse the JSON, not RegEx. Once you parse the JSON with JSON.NET, a new instance of a class will be created where you can simply use `text` and `from` as properties to retrieve the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called deserializing. Here's a related SE question:

[Deserialize JSON with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895105/json-deserialize-c-sharp)